# Not able to click on li element under ul tag

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the below HTML code:

```
<div class="resultDiv">
<span class="">Sort by : </span>
<div class="dropdown num-record">
<button id="dLabel" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
<span class="jsSortTypeText">Relevant</span>
<i class="icon-arrows_down"></i>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" style="display: none;">
<li class="jsSortType" data-value="Prem" data-label="VIP first">VIP first</li>
<li class="jsSortType" data-value="Rec" data-label="Recent">Recent</li>
<li class="jsSortType jsDefaultSort selected" data-value="Rel" data-label="Relevant">Relevant</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to click on the element "dLabel" or "ul" and then click the option "Recent".

I have tried to use action chain,xpath,css selector but nothing works.When using action chain and the test runs without any error but the click does not happen.

Can someone please guide me what I am doing wrong.Below is my code which runs without any errors but does not open the dropdown and select the "Recent" option.

```
        menu1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='dLabel']"))
        clickon = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[6]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]"))
        action = ActionChains(driver)
        action.move_to_element(menu1).perform()
        action.move_to_element(clickon)
        action.click(clickon)
        action.perform()
```

I even tried using something similar to below:

```
    #now find Documents link and click
    recent = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Recent")))
    recent.click()
```

Then I get a timeout error.Maybe I am using the combination wrong or something.

Comment: Please fix your indentation!

Comment: Do you get this xpath from chrome copy xpath?

Comment: i got the xpath from firepath using mozilla.

Comment: fixed the indentation

Comment: if everything fails try using JavascriptExecutor

Comment: have never used that.will try to read about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using expected condition `visibility_of_element_located`, as shown below:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='resultDiv']/div[@class='dropdown num-record']/button[@id='dLabel']")).click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class='resultDiv']/div[@class='dropdown num-record']/ul[@aria-labelledby='dLabel']/li[text()='Recent']')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='resultDiv']/div[@class='dropdown num-record']/ul[@aria-labelledby='dLabel']/li[text()='Recent']").click()
```

UPDATE1: Try following:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='resultDiv']/div[@class='dropdown num-record']/button[@id='dLabel']")).click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class='resultDiv']/descendant::li[text()='Recent']')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='resultDiv']/descendant::li[text()='Recent']").click()
```

Let me know, if you still face the issue.

Comment: Yes it did go one step ahead and it clicked on the dropdown and the dropdown opened but it dint click the dropdown value "Recent"

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\basicactionsselenium-quikr.py", line 98, in test_Login
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='resultDiv']/div[@class='dropdown num-record']/ul[@aria-labelledby='dLabel']/li[text()='Recent']")))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Refer 'UPDATE1' in my answer and let me know, if you still face the issue.

Comment: Yes it is working now.Thanks a lot for the help.The dropdown is still open after clicking but i think it will go away after I add more steps. Can you please help me to understand:

1-what I was doing wrong.
2- What you did and how did you get the xpath which you used in your code

From what I understand is that in your first code you were waiting got the ul to get loaded/visible and in the second part you were waiting for the li to become visible.am i right.

My earlier code was also similar.please let me know why it was not working.

Comment: I have a similar issue:

<div class="panel-body">
<div class="dropdown">
<input class="search-control jsSayt jsRolesFreeText" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Eg: Delivery, BPO, Driver'" placeholder="Eg: Delivery, BPO, Driver" value="" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown" type="text">
<ul class="jsSaytList jsRolesFilter">
<li id="jsFilter_subRole_1" class="checkbox-inline jsFilterSubRole jsRoleValue_1" data-value="Accountant" style="display: block;">

Comment: <input id="Accountant" class="radio-custom jsFilterRadio jsRole" value="Accountant" name="Role" data-roleid="1" type="radio">
<label class="radio-custom-label" for="Accountant">Accountant</label>

code that runs ok but not clicking the radio buttion

 wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='slectrole']/descendant::li[@data-value='Accountant']/label[@for='Accountant']")))

        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='slectrole']/descendant::li[@data-value='Accountant']/label[@for='Accountant']").click()

Comment: 1-what I was doing wrong.: Webdriver was not able to reach the dropdown with the help of the xpath you used. 2- What you did and how did you get the xpath which you used in your code- You are correct. In my answer, I waited for drop-down options to become visible and then clicked on the required option. Additionally, regarding how I found the xpath, I did not use any tool to get the xpath, based on my learnings about xpath, I came up with this xpath. You can refer to the appropriate resources available on web to learn how to find xpath.

Comment: Don't forget to accept and/ or upvote my answer, if it has resolved your issue and you found it useful. I am more than happy to help you on other issues, however, please ask them as a separate questions for better tracking.

Comment: sure I will do that.I have accepted your answer and also voted it. I will post another question

Comment: new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149663/not-able-to-click-radio-button-element-by-xpath-in-selenium-using-python?noredirect=1#comment75316758_44149663 @mahipal