# not able to click radio button element by xpath in selenium using python

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

Below is my HTML

```
<div id="slectrole" class="collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="selectrole">
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="dropdown">
<input class="search-control jsSayt jsRolesFreeText" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Eg: Delivery, BPO, Driver'" placeholder="Eg: Delivery, BPO, Driver" value="" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown" type="text">
<ul class="jsSaytList jsRolesFilter">
<li id="jsFilter_subRole_1" class="checkbox-inline jsFilterSubRole jsRoleValue_1" data-value="Accountant">
<input id="Accountant" class="radio-custom jsFilterRadio jsRole" value="Accountant" name="Role" data-roleid="1" type="radio">
<label class="radio-custom-label" for="Accountant">Accountant</label>
```

Below is the code I am using to click the radio button:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='slectrole']/descendant::li[@data-value='Accountant']/label[@for='Accountant']")))


driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='slectrole']/descendant::li[@data-value='Accountant']/label[@for='Accountant']").click()
```

The code runs ok but it does not select the radio button.

Comment: You are clicking the `<label>`, but your radio-button is at `<input>`, so just go with: `//input[@id='Accountant']`. Your `<label>` just has the text. The functionality lays in the `<input>` field.

Comment: //div[@class='stickySearch']/div[@id='jsSideFilters']/ul[@id='accordion']/li[@id='jsFilter_roles']/div[@class='collapse in']/div[@class='panel-body']/div[@class='dropdown']/ul[@class='jsSaytList jsRolesFilter']/li[1]/input[@value='Accountant']

Comment: //div[@class='stickySearch']/div[@id='jsSideFilters']/ul[@id='accordion']/li[@id='jsFilter_roles']/div[@class='collapse in']/div[@class='panel-body']/div[@class='dropdown']/ul[@class='jsSaytList jsRolesFilter']/li[1]/label[@for='Accountant']

Comment: //div[@class='stickySearch']/div[@id='jsSideFilters']/ul[@id='accordion']/li[@id='jsFilter_roles']/div[@class='collapse in']/div[@class='panel-body']/div[@class='dropdown']/ul[@class='jsSaytList jsRolesFilter']/li[1]

Comment: I tried all the above xpath but none of them is working and it does not click the radio button @Mahipal

Comment: //div[@class='stickySearch']/div[@id='jsSideFilters']/ul[@id='accordion']/li[@id='jsFilter_roles']/div[@class='collapse in']/div[@class='panel-body']/div[@class='dropdown']/ul[@class='jsSaytList jsRolesFilter']/input[@id='Accountant'] is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I can understand your frustration, I tried your code and wasn't able to **.click()** (select) the element when located via `xpath`. See bellow print-screen:
[image]
As you can see, it was only clicking the `radio-button` when issuing a `.click()` via a **CSS**-located element.

**Question No.1:** Are you bound to the `xpath` locator strategy in one way or another?

If NOT, then just use a regulat **CSS** selector: `'input[id="Accountant"]'`.
Else, you have to figure out what is wrong with the website you are testing, or switch to another `WebElement` locator strategy. (e.g.: `ID`, `Class`, `CSS`, `LinkText`, etc.)

If you would opt to go with the **CSS** locator-strategy, then your code would look like this:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='Accountant']")))
driver.find_element_by_css("input[id='Accountant']").click()
```

Alternatively, you can try to click on the `<label>` tag attached to the `radio-button`, which in my console works the same way:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='Accountant']")))
driver.find_element_by_css("label[for='Accountant']").click()
```

**Explanation:** In a real-life scenario, you can select the `radio-button` both via the actual radio-button, or via its label. That's why your solution worked.

**Question No.2:** Why are you using such a long `xpath` selector?

In order to have a optimal selector, you should **ALWAYS** go with the shortest, combination of tags/attributes that will **UNIQUELY** identify your target element. Else you will be susceptible to website changes, flaky test cases, etc.

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'CSS'

Comment: I am using python and selenium webdriver:  
 wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS, "label[for='Accountant']")))
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id='Accountant']").click()

Comment: I am new to selenium and having a tough time using xpath.i tried long xpath just to make sure I am able to select the correct element.I dont need to use xpath.I can use css or anything else that works

Comment: wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='Accountant']")))
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id='Accountant']").click()  I ran the above code.it ran ok but dint click the radio button

Comment: @user8040338 can you retry the snippet of code? I had the wrong argument for the `By` class. It was supposed to be `By.CSS_SELECTOR`. (I'm coming from a Selenium/JavaScript background so Python is not my forte).
 
Btw, you need to pro-actively go online and search for as many solutions as possible, but in order not to do it blindly, I would also recommend reading up the DOC files: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html.

Comment: Yes I tried that by searching online and i dint get any error but it is still not clicking.

Comment: @user8040338 see my updated answer. I am glad this code worked for you `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR‌​, "label[for='Accountant']"))) driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id='Accountant']"‌​).click()`, but that is exactly what I suggested, so I have no idea why you selected a different answer. You are basically using exactly my code, but added more elements to the problem, like filling in the `text-area`, etc. No bueno!

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the click on the drop down and then wait for the radio button to appear, before clicking it. Hence, try following:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='slectrole']/div/div[@class='dropdown']/input[1]")).click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id='slectrole']/descendant::li[@data-value='Accountant']/input[1]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='slectrole']/descendant::li[@data-value='Accountant']/input[1]").click()
```

Let me know, if above code works for you.

Comment: Let me know, if you have any queries.

Comment: I tried this code but it doesnt work.I dont get any error but it still does not click the radio button @Mahipal

Comment: Did it click on the drop-down and options appeared?

Comment: I finally got it to work using below code:

    roleSelect = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='slectrole']/div/div/input"))
    
    roleSelect.send_keys("Accountant")
    
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='Accountant']")))
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id='Accountant']").click()

Can someone please help me understand why the earlier code was not working?

Comment: There is no drop down.There is a input box and radio buttons below it

Comment: oh ok. May be, I misinterpreted the scenario. Good to know that you are able to solve this issue.

Comment: May be you can post your solution as an answer and accept it, if that solution has resolved your issue.

Comment: You are welcome :-). If my answer has not resolved your issue, you do not need to accept it. Instead, once you post your answer, just mark it as accepted, as it has resolved your issue.